# How to implement progress bar in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, progress

I am trying to implement a progress bar in my react js project, but It's not working properly.
Code for child component where I have implemented progress bar -

```
export const Child = (props: ChildProps): React.ReactElement => {
    const { text, showProgress, typeId } = props;
    const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState<number>(0);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
          setProgress((oldProgress) => {
            if (oldProgress === 100) {
              return 0;
            }
            const diff = Math.random() * 100;
            return Math.min(oldProgress + diff, 100);
          });
        }, 500);
    
        return () => {
            if(progress === 100){
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
          
        };
      }, []);
      
      return (
        <Grid container>
            <Grid container item direction="column">
                <Label>{text}</Label>
                <Select
                    options={myOptions}
                    value={mySelectedValue}
                    onChange={(selectedOption: Select<string, string>) =>
                        onChange('TYPE', selectedOption.value, typeId)
                    }
                />
            </Grid>
            {showProgress && (<ProgressBarContainer>
                <ProgressBar color={'Blue'} height={'Small'} progress={progress} />
            </ProgressBarContainer>)
            }
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

I have defined a callback for onChange function in parent component. Everytime I call onChange event, it should display the progress.
Code for parent component -

```
const [showProgress , setShowProgress] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
const [isApiCalled , setIsApiCalled] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
const [myData , setMyData] = React.useState<any>([]);

const onChange = (type: string, value: string, typeid: number): void => {
    if (type === 'TYPE') {
        setShowProgress(true);
        setIsApiCalled(true);
    }
    setMyData(updateData); // I haven't written the code for it here.
}

const saveData = (isSave: boolean): void => {
        callAPI(saveRequestData); // calling API
        setShowProgress(false);
    }
React.useEffect(()=> {
        saveData(true)
        setIsApiCalled(false);
    }, [isApiCalled])
    
return (
            <Child myData={myData} onChange={onChange} showProgress={showProgress} />;
        );
```

Everytime I change the data in `Child`, it should call progress as I am setting the `progress` to be `true`. It is calling the progress but not in a proper way. Like progress should start from `0` everytime I do call onChange and should increase continue. But first time it starts from `0` but it never continue increasing and afterwards it never starts from 0. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have included a progress bar too, more specifically a circular progress bar. I have used an already developed package. You can follow the instructions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar

A simple implementation:

```
import { CircularProgressbar } from "react-circular-progressbar";

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
const points = 30000 //only of testing
 const percentage = (points / 10000) * 100; //calculate the percentage
 return (
        <div>
            <CircularProgressbar value={percentage} text={points} />
        </div>
    );
}
export default MyComponent;
```

For custom styling and CSS, you can copy and modify the code here: https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar/blob/HEAD/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

It seems because of closure, `useEffect()` captures the initial value there on mount and never updates it. Since `Child` is already mounted and `useEffect()` is not called after mount `setInterval` always has initial value of `progress` that is 0 and progress is not updated.

Similar problem is explained by Dan Abramov in his blog:
Excerpt from his blog about this problem

> The problem is that useEffect captures the count from the first
> render. It is equal to 0. We never re-apply the effect so the closure
> in setInterval always references the count from the first render, and
> count + 1 is always 1. Oops!

To solve this, you can use `useRef` hook to capture callback inside interval and on re-render just update it with new reference of the callback. So that setInterval points to updated callback after every interval. Something like:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });
```

You can refer Dan's blog for clear understanding
https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/